# Finding out why my laptop is flooding my NAS

Tags: windows-7, networking, nas

I have a laptop running Windows 7 Home Premium and a QNAP TS-412 network storage unit. For some reason, my laptop apparently sometimes starts bombarding the NAS at TCP ports 445, 139, 80 and UDP port 1900. The NAS box then bans my laptop's IP address to these ports for 5 minutes. The "attack" doesn't continue after the ban is lifted. These incidents always happen at around 5-7pm every few days. The laptop has Microsoft Security Essentials with up-to-date virus definitions and I haven't installed any software from questionable sources. I wasn't actively accessing the NAS in any way when the incidents happened.

The NAS server sends me alerts via email when this happens. Here is an example:

```
 Server Name: Purnukka
 IP Address: 192.168.0.1
 Date/Time: 2013/09/18 08:19:03
 Level:  Warning
 [Security] Access Violation from 192.168.0.106 with TCP (port=80)
```

192.168.0.106 is my laptop's IP, verified from my router's DHCP table.

Is this a common issue? How can I find out which program or system process is responsible?

Comment: What makes you think the laptop is bombarding the NAS? Be as precise as possible.

Comment: Because I get email alerts from the NAS and the IP in the alerts matches my laptop's name in the DHCP table.

Comment: What do the alerts say? Be as precise as possible.

Comment: I updated my question with a sample alert.

Comment: I think the most likely explanation is that the machine is compromised in some way and is scanning your LAN to report back. I'd suggest a sweep for malware using at least two different tools.

Comment: Having a Windows box search for Samba and UPNP is not something that I would think of being abnormal (port 80 is rather less obvious though). @Kaivosukeltaja: Do you know if the ban is triggered for doing just one attempt or is there some sort of of flood of connection attempts? Running a Linux firewall and having occasional Windows laptops behind it has taught me that either Windows or some other rather common software do occasionally seem to do seem to search for network resources even though they are clean.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja: Doing packet caputure on the laptop with Wireshark on traffic between it and the NAS box might explain something, at least for port 80 as the request would likely be clear-text.

Comment: @zagrimsan: To my knowledge, banning is triggered by repeated access violations, the amount being a configurable parameter. I'll check that and set up a Wireshark capture as soon as I get home again.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I ran a Spybot S&D scan, it found nothing but tracking cookies. Is there some other software you could recommend for a quick "second opinion" scan?

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja I'd scan with Malwarebytes just to be 100% sure. Spybot S&D is really good.

Answer (score 0):

Doing [packet capture on the laptop with Wireshark](http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/) on the traffic between it and the NAS box might explain something, at least for port 80 as the request would likely be clear-text and give a clue on what and why is being attempted.

Even though malware infection is always a valid suspicion, what I suspect here is that there is an application related to multimedia and/or file sync/sharing that has scheduled update/search for network resources. It might be hard to track it, though, unless you set up some sort of a tool to constantly monitor the open connections. One simple yet crude, ugly and suboptimal way is to have the following command running on the laptop around the time the issue tends to happen.

```
netstat -no 1 | findstr "192.168.0.1" | findstr "445 139 80 1900" > logfile.txt
```

Then you would see from the output `logfile.txt` the ID of the process (the last number on the row) that initiates those connections and could try finding it from Task Manager process list (you need to add `PID` column there from `View` -> `Select columns...` if it is not there already). This will clearly fail if the process quits right after the connection attempts, but in that case you could try adding `-b` to the parameters of `netstat` (i.e. `netstat -nob 1 | ...`) - need to run cmd.exe with admin privileges for that to work, though.